# Can C# MVC act as standalone web api service?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Lately I've been having problems returning JSON responses to a PHP and JQuery based url. I use the post request as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        (function(){
            console.log("ran");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://chad-test4.clas.university.edu/Employees/Edit/22",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("Response recieved");
                        console.log("Success: " + data);
                        empData = data;
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log("Failed");
                    }
            });
        })();
    });
```

My Controller is:

```
public JsonResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return Json("Error: Id does not exist",     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        employee chad = db.employees.Find(1);

        if (chad == null)
        {
            return Json("Error: employee does not exist", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        chad.last_name = "Changed"; 
        chad.netid = "1111111";
        db.Entry(chad).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();


        Console.WriteLine("Successfully gotten");
        return Json(chad, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            

    }
```

This keeps either returning a full HTML page, or an error with the following console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).alert is not a function(anonymous function) 
@misc.js:633
display:410 ran
misc.js:783 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of
undefinedcalculateTotalPurposesAmount @ misc.js:783window.onload 
@misc.js:627
display:421 Failed
```

Do I need to instead make a Web API project so that only JQuery data is returned?

Comment: What is the content of the returned HTML page?

Comment: An almost view-type of file with form elements filled with the correct information for the user entered in the URL

Comment: Are you sure your routes are set up right? You're not hitting the wrong action method on accident are you?

Comment: Also, work on the two problems separately, go and download like RestConsole and troubleshoot your api. Then once thats working, go ahead and try hitting it from your jquery

Comment: Are you making a cross-origin request? If so did it ever work? CORS?